# Is it possible to create and empty div (as a line break) and give it a border bottom and bottom box shadow

Tags: css

I have tried the following code to create a line break with a box shadow below it. the border bottom works fine but no shadow appears. I works ok if I have content in it but im trying to get it to be empty if possible.

```
<div class="break"></div>

.break{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid $txt;
    box-shadow:0 1px 1px $shadow;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 20px -20px $shadow;
}
```

Comment: This may be helpful in better understanding box-shadow: [http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Add a margin to your div like so: `margin: -50px auto 10px;`

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/NsqZp/2/)

```
.break{
    width: 90%;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1f1209;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 20px -20px #333;
    margin: -50px auto 10px;
}
```

---

I think this is what you need:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/zYnpB/1/)**

```
.break{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    margin: 20px 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px #333;

}
```

Comment: This is the result im looking just without a height, if you change the height to 0 the shadow goes completely jsfiddle.net/NsqZp

Comment: @PierceMcGeough I updated the fiddle .. I gave the border-bottom a value transparent...i think that's what you want

Comment: Still not working. I need something like this http://jsfiddle.net/NsqZp/1/ The -20 brings the shadow back in the way i need it. You can see the difference if you change it to just 20

Comment: So then what is wrong with your fiddle?? I see the border-bottom and the shadow below it? What do you need?

Comment: Need a 0 height. I just want to use it as a line break.

Comment: @PierceMcGeough I updated the answer/fiddle - just add a negative top margin with a positive bottom margin

Comment: This is a nice effect. If the style is meant to represent a thematic break between sections of content, using the `<hr>` element would be a more appropriate than an empty div. http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/hr.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you had 2 box-shadow, but most importantly you declared 0 on your offset?
I tried this on fiddle:
[js fiddle test](http://jsfiddle.net/5DExJ/)

```
.break{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    padding: 0 0 0px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000; 
    box-shadow: 5px 7px 7px #aaa;
    /*box-shadow: 5px 20px 20px -20px #ddd;*/
        height:1px;
        line-height:1px;
}
```

Note: adding height and line height instead of padding;

Comment: This is the result im looking just without a height, if you change the height to 0 the shadow goes completely http://jsfiddle.net/NsqZp/

Answer (score 0):

Your box-shadow (why do you have two?) has too large of a negative spread on it. Try it with values -5 or less. `box-shadow: 0 20px 20px -5px rgba(100,100,100,0.4)` works fine for me.